# how can i convert a big number to ZonedDateTime java field

Tags: java, java-8

How can I convert a number like this : 1467158498669 from à json file to java field of type : ZonedDateTime ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Instant.ofEpochMilli`

```
long date = 1467158498669l;

ZonedDateTime zoneTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date).atZone(ZoneId.of("Canada/Atlantic"));
```

OR

```
ZonedDateTime  zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(date),
            ZoneId.of("Canada/Atlantic"));
```

Comment: You're right, that's much easier, thanks;>